# Convergence of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}\sin x}{(e^x-1)\log(1+x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Could someone please help me determine wether the following integral converges: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}\sin x}{(e^x-1)\log(1+x)}dx$$
I have no idea how to start unfortunately... So any hint will be appreciated

Comment: Can you identify the problematic points?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that $x\geq\ln(1+x)$?  If so, just replace everything with bounds except for the $e^x$ terms and then use the fact that $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}$ converges.

Answer (score 4):

In zero, you have

$\sin(x) \sim x$, $e^x-1 \sim x$ and $\log(1+x) \sim x$

This imply

$$\left|\frac{\sqrt{x} \sin(x)}{(e^x-1)\log(1+x)}\right| \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$

So your integral converge in 0

And in $+\infty$, you have

$$\left|\frac{\sqrt{x} \sin(x)}{(e^x-1)\log(1+x)}\right| \leq \frac{\sqrt{x}}{e^x-1} \sim \sqrt{x}e^{-x}$$

And $$\int_1^{\infty} \sqrt{x}e^{-x}dx < +\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}\sin x}{(e^x-1)\log(1+x)}dx&\leq\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}x}{(e^x-1)\log(1+x)}dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{x}(x+1)^y}{e^x-1}dydx\\
&\leq \int_0^\infty \int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{x}(x+1)^1}{e^x-1}dydx\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}(x+1)}{e^x-1}dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\frac52-1}}{e^x-1}dx+\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\frac32-1}}{e^x-1}dx\\
&=\zeta(\frac52)\Gamma(\frac52)+\zeta(\frac32)\Gamma(\frac32)
<\infty
\end{align}

Comment: Talk about overkill! While this is fun I doubt it is of any help for the OP :-)

Comment: @Ant I agree with the fun part :-)